# How to align widgets to other widgets

Tags: android

I am new all around design of UI inn android. and i have a 3 alignments problem in the follwoing image:
1. i would like that the rotatte laeft and right will be under the cent of the butoom "Select Photo".
2. for some reason the spinner near to the mobile edit text is not in the hegiht of the mobile edittext.
3.the "Create Account" buttom should be in the Bottom of the screen. but even when i add the following line:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

nothing happend.

this is what i get in my device:
[image]

this is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffffff"
tools:context="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Register">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/submainLayout"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGallery"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:hint="Email"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMobile"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            android:background="#606060"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSelectImg"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSelectImg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextMobile"
            android:layout_weight="21.24" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextMobile"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:hint="Mobile"
            android:layout_weight="40.74" />



    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:hint="Password"

            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow5"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPass"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow6"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Gender:"
            android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="5.18" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:layout_weight="2.84" />



    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow7"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Year of Birth:"
            android:id="@+id/textViewyearOfBirth"
            android:layout_weight="5.18" />



        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAge"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:layout_weight="3.14" />

    </TableRow>





    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow8"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewGallery"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rotateLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Photo"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelectImg"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signupRow9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewGallery">


    </TableRow>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:background="#606060"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/rotateLayout"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewGallery">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonRleftt"
            android:background="@drawable/rotate_left"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonRright"
            android:background="@drawable/rotate_right"
            android:onClick="rottateRight"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSubmit"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#606060"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow7"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >

    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just set the width for both drawables to "wrap_content" and delete the weight attribute. Then add the gravity attribute to the table row like this:

   ```
   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/signupRow9"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow8"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewGallery"
       android:gravity="center">

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageButtonRleftt"
           android:src="@drawable/rotate_right"/>

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageButtonRright"
           android:src="@drawable/rotate_right"
           android:onClick="rottateRight"/>
   </TableRow>
   ```
2. The easiest way is to define a static height for you tablerow and then set the height attribute for your spinner and edittext to "match_parent". Another way is to get the height of your edittext programmatically and then set the height for the spinner at runtime. I would recommend the second method, because it looks better for different devices.
3. You're using the wrong attribute. Try it with android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to set the View to the top.

Comment: i made a mistake in section 3 its should be in the bottom.

Comment: on the picture the button is at the bottom

Comment: look at the picture now. the button height is much bigger than he should.

Comment: please try to delete the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" attribute this should reduce the size. Otherwise try to reduce the height of the button.

Comment: ok i found the mistake. i need to remove android:layout_below="@+id/signupRow7"

Comment: good but be careful this could cause some displaying bugs on small devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98812/discussion-between-ryuzz-and-matant).

Answer (score 1):

For the

1)use a single/separate table layout and add first row as "SELECT PHOTO" using colspan attribute and for the second row add the buttons using weight Attribute.

2)Instead of using warpcontent for both of them set layout_height="50dp" or anything, such that it's similar to other widgets in terms of height.

3)use CreateAccount widget directly without a tablerow with this attribute android:layout_alignParentTop="true" such that the parent of this widget is Relativelayout.

Comment: for your answer about 3 what i got that the button location is on top its shouldn't be bottom?

Comment: and when i use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" i got thhat the height of the button is all the white space between "Year of Birth" to the bottom of the screen

Comment: @matant I did not get you can please share the screenshot and explain me from that image or tell me what is your requirement regarding CreateAccount button.

Comment: i would like that the button will be in the bottom of the screen. now what i get that the button is in the bottom but is height is from the textview "year of birth" to the bottom. and i would like that is hegit will be as a regular button but in the bottom.

Comment: did you try reducing the height of the button "android:layout_height="50dp"" for create account